# Socket Inputstream doesn't return -1 at the end of stream

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream, serversocket, bytearrayoutputstream

This is a code snippet where the problem is happening:

```
public static byte[] copyLargeExt(InputStream input) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024*8];
        int n = 0;
        while(-1 != (n = input.read(buffer))) {
            baos.write(buffer, 0, n);
        // i just append this pattern ({###END###}) to force the break  
           /*if(baos.toString(UTF8.name()).endsWith("{###END###}")) {
                break;
            }*/
        }
        return baos.toByteArray();
    }
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: So that just loops forever? Where is your input stream from?

Comment: It just not loop forever but it returns nothing. The input stream is from Google(Postman)

Comment: The end of the stream would be reached when the socket is closed. Who is closing the socket?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7599742/how-do-i-recognize-eof-in-java-sockets

Comment: The socket muss be closed only after writing back to outputstream

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in the question reads to the end of the socket stream.  If the method is blocking and in the read call, then that can only mean that the other end has not closed its corresponding output stream yet.

You have two choices:

- Change the other end to close its outputstream so that this code will see an EOF.
- Change the "protocol" so that this code knows how many bytes of data to expect ... and reads exactly that number of bytes.

Answer (score 1):

In Java.
If the Server only `Socket.close()` without `OutputStream.close()` first, the Client's `InputStream.read()` will not return `-1`.
Instead, the Client's `InputStream.read()` will block until timeout.
So the best practice on Server is:

```
OutputStream.close();
InputStream.close();
Socket.close();
```

Comment: I wonder what it does in `InputStream.close()`? Does this sends a special character to mean EOF?